# how to uninstalling HTTP Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2013

can some one help me, i have error when install Visual studio 2013 and i got reference to solve my problem with uninstalling HTTP Debugger.

```
how can i uninstall HTTP Debugger in windows 8?
```

please help